# Attempting to present <ViewController> on <UITabBarController> whose View is not in Window Hierarchy

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Im trying to present a login screen from a TabBarController . But i get the following log message and the view controller is not navigating.

> projectlogin[3372:60b] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

What i did was,ctrl+drag a segue to a viewcontroller(Login) and given identifier as viewcontroller  (push).I make  call from ViewDidLoad

```
[self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewcontroller" sender:self];
```

I tried it it ViewWillAppear also,but no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it from  **ViewDidAppear** rather than ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.